# Is there a better alternative to Line Break

Tags: html, css

Sometimes after a `<div>` class the next line comes on the same line and I need to put say 10 `<br>` to get it to the next line.

Is this okay or is there an alternative to this?

Everything works out fine, it's just that I need to put 10 `<br>`. Is this normal?

Thank You

GOT IT TO WORK USING CLEAR:BOTH. THANKS.

Comment: Class? CSS class? school? social-economic class?

Comment: ".... the next line comes on the same line ... " Hehe...

Comment: sounds like you are floating the class? Please give more information :)

Comment: 10 <br> tags, I assume... He forgot to style them as code, so they don't appear in the text.

Comment: If I had to guess, I think the OP is saying that sometimes when positioning text with CSS, some text gets positioned in a way that overlaps other text on the page, but adjusting the text's position by 10 (em, pt, px?) "fixes" this. For example, he's positioning one `div` on top of another `div` via CSS rules and then compensating.

Comment: @FutureKode Yep. I am using  float class. Sorry abt the language, my keyboard is horrible. after a <div> class with float:left; line breaks- <br>

Comment: Can you just paste your code into your answer? That will make this much easier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to clear after your floating elements.
Put this after the elements:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<!-- Now you won't need <br/> to display text here -->
```

Comment: @jack, since this worked for you, consider marking it as the "accepted" answer by clicking the hollow checkmark under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not normal

Comment: I disagree. Since it is happening, it is true, ergo, normal.

Comment: How would you know its happening ? So far I have not seen a shred of supporting evidence =)

Comment: Hehe. Well, something IS happening. And the OP asked if that (what is happening) is normal. I would say so. (Unless someone hacked his browser)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I understand what you mean...

```
<div style="float:left"> some text here... </div>

<div> some other text ... </div>
```

If you want the second DIV to be pushed below the first DIV, you have to set its clear property to left:

```
<div style="float:left"> some text here... </div>

<div style="clear:left"> some other text ... </div>
```